# How to send SMS to mobile phone using SignalR in MVC?

Tags: signalr, smsmanager

How start a project SMS to send message to local mobile phones using SignalR technology. Any help in this regards will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignalR is used to send data via WebSockets. What you want to achieve is completely different.

You could use SignalR to for example, send notifications to your phone to an app but SMS is not a responsibility of SignalR.

You can read more about SignalR [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Normally, we are using third party sms gateway web page to send sms to our students (bulk or individual). Now thinking to integrate that sms gateway into our MVC apps. But not sure how to make a good start to integrate. After googling showed up SignalR therefore need bit clarification am I on right path if use SignalR for this purpose.

Comment: @NadeemTaj for notifications yes, sms no.

Comment: save my time nice explanation. It opens the research door for me for: a) collect information. b) Notify sms-gateway. c) finally sms-gatway send the sms to mobile / cell no.